# How to copy a string into middle of character pointer

Tags: c, string, pointers, strcpy

I have a dynamically allocated char array with pre_padding_buffer (size 8) and post_padding_buffer (size 6). I need to copy the string over to a character pointer like this:

```
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][e][x][a][m][p][l][e][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
```

The paddings are not optional and required by the specs of a machine I'm communicating with (it can be filled with empty/garbage data, it's overwritten anyways).

Currently this is what I'm doing.

```
unsigned char *async_string = get_async_string();

unsigned char *response_all_buf = (unsigned char*)malloc(LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING + strlen(async_string) + LWS_SEND_BUFFER_POST_PADDING);

//Copy string
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < strlen(async_string); i++) {
    response_all_buf[LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING + i] = async_string[i];
}

libwebsocket_write(wsi,respones_all_buf,strlen(async_string),LWS_WRITE_TEXT);
free(response_all_buf); //<-- Segmentation fault here
```

Segmentation fault must indicate that I'm not copying the string correctly. What's the correct way of doing this when you have paddings to insert before and after?

Comment: Seg Fault is always due to accessing memory out of bound or unallocated memory.

Comment: Is this C or C++? Pick one.

Comment: ...but, isn't libwebsocket_write async? in this case you shouldn't free( ) his datas before it finishes his task

Comment: Did you `#include` `<stdlib.h>`?

Comment: If this is C, then [do NOT cast the return value of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858).

Comment: In terms how the data is copied the code looks ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The neat method:

```
response_all_buf = malloc(8 + strlen(async_string) + 6);
memset(response_all_buf, ' ', (8 + strlen(async_string) + 6));
memcpy(response_all_buf + 8, async_string, strlen(async_string));
```

Or, as you say padding can contain garbage:
You can do it this way:

```
response_all_buf = malloc(8 + strlen(async_string) + 6);
memcpy(response_all_buf + 8, async_string, strlen(async_string));
```

Answer (score 0):

Firs of all response_all_buf[LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING + i] = async_string[i];

- This is not advisable when you are dealing with strings or characters  . As suggested by 0XF1 you can follow the approach where you have the control over the response_all_buf very well .